# How to measure power spectral density in matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectral-density

I am trying to measure the PSD of a stochastic process in matlab, but I am not sure how to do it. I have posted the exact same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468290/30734), but I thought I might have more luck here.

The stochastic process describes wind speed, and is represented by a vector of real numbers. Each entry corresponds to the wind speed in a point in space, measured in m/s. The points are 0.0005 m apart. How do I measure and plot the PSD? Let's call the vector `V`. My first idea was to use

```
[p, w] = pwelch(V);
loglog(w,p);
```

But is this correct? The thing is, that I'm given an analytical expression, which the PSD should (in theory) match. By plotting it with these two lines of code, it looks all wrong. Specifically it looks as though it could need a translation and a scaling. Other than that, the shapes of the two are similar.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
The image above actually doesn't depict the PSD obtained by using `pwelch` on a single vector, but rather the mean of the PSD of 200 vectors, since these vectors stems from numerical simulations. As suggested, I have tried scaling by 2*pi/0.0005. I saw that you can actually give this information to `pwelch`. So I tried using the code

```
[p, w] = pwelch(V,[],[],[],2*pi/0.0005);
loglog(w,p);
```

instead. As seen below, it looks much nicer. It is, however, still not perfect. Is that just something I should expect? Taking the squareroot is not the answer, by the way. But thanks for the suggestion. For one thing, it should follow Kolmogorov's -5/3 law, which it does now (it follows the green line, which has slope -5/3). The function I'm trying to match it with is the Shkarofsky spectral density function, which is the one-dimensional Fourier transform of the Shkarofsky correlation function. Is it not possible to mark up math, here on the site?

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
I have tried using `[p, w] = pwelch(V,[],[],[],1/0.0005);` as I was suggested. But as you can seem it still doesn't quite match up. It's hard for me to explain exactly what I'm looking for. But what I would like (or, what I expected) is that the dip, of the computed and the analytical PSD happens at the same time, and falls off with the same speed. The data comes from simulations of turbulence. The analytical expression has been fitted to actual measurements of turbulence, wherein this dip is present as well. I'm no expert at all, but as far as I know the dip happens at the small length scales, since the energy is dissipated, due to viscosity of the air.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468290/how-to-measure-power-spectral-density-in-matlab

Comment: Yes. Just as I stated in the first paragraph.

Comment: It would not hurt to see: (1) the analytical expression (in particular units) (2) the data. Even better post a minimal working example of your problem.

Comment: Seems to me the shortcoming might be with the analytical theory which does not account for the viscosity of air and does not come up with the nice dip?

Comment: No, it does. You can see the dip in the analytical PSD as well. Unless you by "dip" means the sort of "upside down peak" (or whatever)? Then it doesn't. But the part of the computed PSD where it grows actually surprised me, since it is not supposed to do that.

Comment: Ahh, that is what I meant by dip!

Comment: In any case what I am calling a "dip" is probably your biggest problem at this point, I would look for a clear explanation for that...

Comment: You probably want to look into function `welch` (not spectrum.welch) and see what it's doing. It could be that dip is due to a filter? Default window appears to be `hamming`

Answer (score 1):

What about using the standard equation for obtaining a `PSD`? I'd would do this way:

```
Sxx(f) = (fft(x(t)).*conj(fft(x(t))))*(dt^2);
```

or

```
Sxx = fftshift(abs(fft(x(t))))*(dt^2);
```

Then, if you really need, you may think of applying a windowing criterium, such as

- Hanning
- Hamming
- Welch

which will only somehow filter your `PSD`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would `dt` be in my case? The powerspectrum I get from these two are symmetrical - is that supposed to happen? If I wanted to plot these - say by `loglog(w,Sxx(f))` - what would `w` then need to be?

Comment: @cimrg.joe: I suppose that the time series are accompanied by a time-stamp or similar. Am I wrong? Besides, the `PSD` for a real signal is supposed to be symmetric and it's generally called `double-sided PSD`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you need to rescale the frequency (wavenumber) to units of 1/m. 
The frequency units from `pwelch` should be rescaled, since as the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html) explains:

> W is the vector of normalized frequencies at which the PSD is
>       estimated.  W has units of rad/sample.

Off the cuff my guess is that the scaling factor is

```
 scale = 1/0.0005/(2*pi);
```

or 318.3 (m^-1).

As for the intensity, it looks like taking a square root might help. Perhaps your equation reports an intensity, not PSD?

**Edit**

As you point out, since the analytical and computed PSD have nearly identical slopes they appear to obey similar power laws up to 800 m^-1. I am not sure to what degree you require exponents or offsets to match to be satisfied with a specific model, and I am not familiar with this particular theory.

As for the apparent inconsistency at high wavenumbers, I would point out that you are entering the domain of very small numbers and therefore (1) floating point issues and (2) noise are probably lurking. The very nice looking dip in the computed PSD on the other hand appears very real but I have no explanation for it (maybe your noise is not white?).

You may want to look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28865-3-d-propagation-code/content/AtmosphereScintillation/Shkarofsky.m) submission at matlab central as it may be useful.

**Edit #2**

After inspecting documentation of `pwelch`, it appears that you should pass `1/0.0005` (the sampling rate) and not `2*pi/0.0005`. This should not affect the slope but will affect the intercept.

Comment: Realized I took the wrong value to compute the scaling factor and changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have tried passing the sampling rate to `pwelch` instead, but what is produces is actually even further from what I expected. I have updated my question with an explanation of the dip.

Comment: Hmmm, but I would argue that inputing the sampling rate is consistent with both the documentation and simple numerical tests of the behavior of pwelch.

Answer (score 0):

The dip in PSD in your simulation results looks similar to aliasing artifacts
that I have seen in my data when the original data were interpolated with a
low-order method.  To make this clearer - say my original data was spaced at
0.002m, but in the course of cleaning up missing data, trying to save space, whatever, 
I linearly interpolated those data onto a 0.005m spacing.  The frequency response 
of linear interpolation is not well-behaved, and will introduce peaks and valleys
at the high wavenumber end of your spectrum.

There are different conventions for spectral estimates - whether the wavenumber
units are 1/m, or radians/m.  Single-sided spectra or double-sided spectra.

> help pwelch

shows that the default settings return a one-sided spectrum, i.e. the bin for some
frequency ω will include the power density for both +ω and -ω.
You should double check that the idealized spectrum to which you are comparing
is also a one-sided spectrum.  Otherwise, you'll need to half the values of your
one-sided spectrum to get values representative of the +ω side of a 
two-sided spectrum.

I agree with Try Hard that it is the cyclic frequency (generally Hz, or in this case 1/m)
which should be specified to pwelch.  That said, the returned frequency vector
from pwelch is *also* in those units.  Analytical
spectral formulae are usually written in terms of angular frequency, so you'll
want to be sure that you evaluate it in terms of radians/m, but scale back to 1/m
for plotting.